# Cannot generate predictions in mgcv when using discretization (discrete=T)

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am fitting a model using a random site-level effect using a generalized additive model, implemented in the `mgcv` package for R. I had been doing this using the function `gam()` however, to speed things up I need to shift to the `bam()` framework, which is basically the same as `gam()`, but faster. I further sped up fitting by passing the options `bam(nthreads = N, discrete=T)`, where `nthreads` is the number of cores on my machine. However, when I use the discretization option, and then try to make predictions with my model on new data, while ignoring the random effect, I consistent get an error.

Here is code to generate example data and reproduce the error.

```
library(mgcv)
#generate data.
N <- 10000
x <- runif(N,0,1)
y <- (0.5*x / (x + 0.2)) + rnorm(N)*0.1 #non-linear relationship between x and y.

#uninformative random effect.
random.x <- as.factor(do.call(paste0, replicate(2, sample(LETTERS, N, TRUE), FALSE)))


#fit models.
fit1 <- gam(y ~ s(x) + s(random.x, bs = 're')) #this one takes ~1 minute to fit, rest faster.
fit2 <- bam(y ~ s(x) + s(random.x, bs = 're'))
fit3 <- bam(y ~ s(x) + s(random.x, bs = 're'), discrete = T, nthreads = 2)

#make predictions on new data.
newdat <- data.frame(runif(200, 0, 1))
colnames(newdat) <- 'x'
test1 <- predict(fit1, newdata=newdat, exclude = c("s(random.x)"), newdata.guaranteed = T)
test2 <- predict(fit2, newdata=newdat, exclude = c("s(random.x)"), newdata.guaranteed = T)
test3 <- predict(fit3, newdata=newdat, exclude = c("s(random.x)"), newdata.guaranteed = T)
```

Making predictions with the third model which uses discretization throws this error (which the other two do not):

```
Error in model.frame.default(object$dinfo$gp$fake.formula[-2], newdata) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'random.x')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 200 rows but variables found have 10000 rows
```

How can I go about making predictions for a new dataset using the model fit with discretization?

Answer (score 2):

`newdata.gauranteed` doesn't seem to be working for `bam()` models with `discrete = TRUE`. You could email the author and maintainer of *mgcv* and send him the reproducible example so he can take a look. See `?bug.reports.mgcv`.

You probably want

```r
names(newdat) <- "x"
```

as data frames have `names`.

But the workaround is just to pass in something for `random.x`

```r
newdat <- data.frame(x = runif(200, 0, 1), random.x = random.x[[1]])
```

and then do your call to generate `test3` and it will work.

The warning message and error are the result of you not specifying `random.x` in the newdata and then mgcv looking for `random.x` and finding it in the global environment. You should really gather that variables into a data frame and use the `data` argument when you are fitting your models, and try not to leave similarly named objects lying around in your global environment.